# Theia Sticky Sidebar doesn't work in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, javascript

My HTML template use Theia Sticky Sidebar - and it works in plain HTML.

When this HTML is transformed to SharePoint masterpage and layouts the script doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in SharePoint layout.

Standard HTML `<body>` is actually `<div id="#s4-workspace">`. And when you scroll page, scroll event is fired on **#s4-workspace** element.

So, to make Theia Sticky Sidebar work (or any other Sticky plugin) - you have to change original JS.

Change all `document` selectors like this:

```
$(document).on('scroll.' + options.namespace, function (options, $that)..
```

to this:

```
$("#s4-workspace").on('scroll.' + options.namespace, function (options, $that)....
```

And all `body` elements:

```
if ($('body').width() < options.minWidth) {
            return false;
}
```

change to this:

```
if ($('#s4-workspace').width() < options.minWidth) {
            return false;
}
```

And this one: `$(document).scrollLeft();` to this: `$("#s4-workspace").scrollLeft();`

Also, it's good idea to use Sticky Sidebar only when page is in display mode and set additional margin top to height of the ribbon plus few pixel like this:

```
if (inDesignMode != "1") {
        // Theia Sticky Sidebar @ display-mode
        $('.sidebar').theiaStickySidebar({
            "additionalMarginTop": $("#ms-designer-ribbon").height()+10,
        })
    }
```

When you set additional margin top like this, it will work both for the administrators and for readers. As sometimes, in my projects, I'm hiding ribbon for readers.